# Visualizar en un dropDownList el nombre y el apellido

Tags: c#, .net

Quiero visualizar en un dropDownList tanto el nombre como el apellido de un trabajador. Cada uno de los datos está en una columna independiente. Aqui esta el codigo que me visualiza el nombre del trabajador en el dropDownList. Gracias.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblTrabajador.Text = Session["Nombre"] + " " + Session["Apellido1"];
            cmdNombreAreaTrabajo.Connection = conexion;
            cmdNombreTrabajador.Connection = conexion;
            conexion.Open();
            cmdNombreAreaTrabajo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdNombreTrabajador.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Visualizo el dropDownList AreaTrabajo
            daNombreAreaTrabajo = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdNombreAreaTrabajo);
            daNombreAreaTrabajo.Fill(dtNombreAreaTrabajo);
            ddlAreaTrabajo.DataSource = dtNombreAreaTrabajo;
            ddlAreaTrabajo.DataTextField = "NombreAreaTrabajo";
            ddlAreaTrabajo.DataValueField = "NombreAreaTrabajo";
            ddlAreaTrabajo.DataBind();

            //Visualizo el dropDownList NombreTrabajador y Apellido
            daNombreTrabajador = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdNombreTrabajador);
            daNombreTrabajador.Fill(dtNombreTrabajador);
            ddlNombreTrabajador.DataSource = dtNombreTrabajador;
            ddlNombreTrabajador.DataTextField = "Nombre";
            ddlNombreTrabajador.DataValueField = "Nombre";
            ddlNombreTrabajador.DataBind();

            conexion.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: No veo ninguna dropdownlist en ese código.

Comment: Hazlo en la query  pe: select Nombre+' '+Apellido1 as Nombre2

Comment: Y luego ddlNombreTrabajador.DataTextField = "Nombre2";

Comment: Muchas gracias francisco!

Comment: Las porciones de código son para mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, no para poner código "porque sí". Como te han dicho, allí no hay ningún dropdownlist. Recuerda que la pregunta y sus potenciales respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar.